# LINUX + red hat + How to define swap on disk partition: /dev/cciss/c0d0p6

Tags: linux, swap

How to define swap (8G usage) on disk partition: /dev/cciss/c0d0p6 ( i have Linux red hat 5.3)

```
for example:
in my machine I not have swap definition 

Swap:            0          0          0


the target is to create the following swap:
swapon -s 

Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/cciss/c0d0p6                       partition       8385888 0       -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkswap /dev/cciss/c0d0p6
echo '/dev/cciss/c0d0p6 none swap sw 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
swapon -a
```

Comment: please fix to /etc/fstab